# How to get values from comment in php

Tags: php

I have a comment in php file how do i get say Name: value or Type: value from the comment as in wordpress.

```
<?php 
 /*
  Name: My name
  Description: The description
  Type: File-type
 */
 ?>
```

I tried this but could only get name can't go further.

```
        $tokens = token_get_all(file_get_contents("filename.php"));
        $comments = array();
        foreach($tokens as $token) {
            if($token[0] == T_COMMENT || $token[0] == T_DOC_COMMENT) {
                $comments[] = $token[1];
            }
        }
        $_to_string = trim(current($comments), "\**/");
        $split_str = str_split($_to_string, stripos($_to_string, "Description"));
        $explode_str = explode(":",$split_str[0]);
echo $explode_str[1];
```

Comment: i think by using `file_get_content()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to split up the comment by lines first and then for each line try and split it by the :.  If there are two components then you can use this for your data.  I use the first part as the key for the output and the second as the value (remembering to `trim()` to clean them up)...

```
$_to_string = trim(current($comments), "\**/");
$out = [];
foreach ( explode(PHP_EOL, $_to_string) as $item )  {
    $itemData = explode(":",$item);
    if ( count($itemData) == 2 )    {
        $out[trim($itemData[0])] = trim($itemData[1]);
    }
}
print_r($out);
```

Which with your sample gives...

```
Array
(
    [Name] => My name
    [Description] => The description
    [Type] => File-type
)
```